# How to print the result of a stored proc in template using pagination?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I used below code to run a stored proc in Django -

```
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute('exec [dbo].[usp_mytest] %s, %s, %s, %s,', (field1, difference, age, aginggrp))
queryset1 = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
```

Now, I want to print the type of this queryset1 and did the below:

`return HttpResponse(queryset1[0][1])` - This gives me the value of the first field I am expected to get.

I am doing it in a function in **views.py**

I want to use pagination against this queryset1 and writing below code:

```
paginator = Paginator(queryset1, 25)

try:
    page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
except:
    page = 1
try:
    type1 = paginator.page(page)
except('EmptyPage', 'InvalidPage'):
    type1 = paginator.page(1)


return render(request, 'index.html', {
                'type1': type1,
                 'page_range': page_range,
             })
```

But it is giving error for page_range and as soon as I comment this page_rane line from render() and comment the above pagination code, it gives me blank page.

Can someone please suggest me the way to do pagination here?

Answer (score 0):

Please, turn on **settins.py** `DEBUG=True` and copy paste your error trace, 
Only then can we help you better.